# Calculating the time duration of a particular Log event using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash, kibana

Objective : I want to to calculate the time duration on how long a particualr event has lasted using logstash.

Scenario : Consider a customer Who is searching for a product to purchase from my page. Each and every page he is visiting has been recorded in the log along with time duration. Now I want to find how long an Average customer is taking to get a product. and how long my server is taking time to respond him back.

Now here is my Log file:
`16-09-2004 00:37:22 BEGIN_CUST 
ts:16-09-2004T00:37:26+05:30
ID-XYZ456
16-09-2004 00:37:23 PAGE_1
ID-XYZ456
ts:16-09-2004T00:39:26+05:30
16-09-2004 00:37:23 PAGE_2
ID-XYZ456
ts:16-09-2004T00:41:26+05:30
16-09-2004 00:37:23 BUT_REQ
ID-XYZ456
ts:16-09-2004T00:43:26+05:30
16-09-2004 00:37:23 PURCHASE
ID-XYZ456
ts:16-09-2004T00:47:26+05:30
16-09-2004 00:51:22 BEGIN_CUST 
ts:16-09-2004T00:52:26+05:30
ID-YUB98I
16-09-2004 00:53:23 PAGE_1
ID-YUB98I
16-09-2004 00:55:23 PURCHASE
ID-YUB98I`

In the above log file, It is clear that `BEGIN_CUST` is the beginning of the event and `PURCHASE` is the end of an event.
ID (plays as a unique ID for each customer).

I have tried Scripted fields. but it is not yielding me proper results due to the following points,

- It is not necessary that a customer needs to purchase it.
- Customer Purchase may last even in Seconds.

Is there any way better to plot the duration of an Individual Customer in a separate field in Kibana to visualize it using Logstash.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you're using ElasticSearch as your store, [the `elasticsearch` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) may do what you need. The trick is to search for the `BEGIN_CUST` event as soon as you get a `PURCHASE` event. The documentation for this plugin includes and example that does much of what you're looking for, but here is a summary:

```
if [trans_type] == "PURCHASE" {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => localhost,
    query => "trans_type:BEGIN_CUST AND cust_id:%{[cust_id]}],
    fields => { "@timestamp" => "started" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "[started]", "ISO8601" ]
    target => "[started]"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event['shopping_time'] = (event['@timestamp'] - event['started'] rescue nil"
  }
}
```

Which will yield a `shopping_time` field measured in seconds between when the `BEGIN_CUST` record arrived and when the first `PURCHASE` arrived. If a customer purchases twice, then each `PURCHASE` record will have its own `shopping_time` field based on the same `BEGIN_CUST`.

This works by querying ElasticSearch for the BEGIN_CUST record, and using the `@timestamp` data on that record in the PURCHASE record's `started` field. The `date {}` filter then turns that into a datetime data-type. Finally, the `ruby {}` block computes the difference in time between the current `@timestamp` field and the one pulled out of ElasticSearch, creating the `shopping_time` field.

Comment: checked it. did some modifications. now it is working fine :)